# How do you create a "linked list" of Story nodes in Drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to link together a number of pages in a regular flow in Drupal. The way I've been doing it recently, is to create a new Menu and then seperately create a page for each menu item.

For example, I have a menu block with links One through to Six. I then create six pages and link One to node/1, Two to node/2, Three to node/3 and so on.

This is fine, but I'm told that I can create a number of story nodes instead, and they'll link together at the bottom of the page like so (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD1HX.jpg) without my intervention, almost like a linked list of page nodes.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out. I had to enable the book module. Co-worker just explained to me after reading the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you already solved it, but just FYI, you can also use the [Custom Pagers](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_pagers) module to do this as an alternative to the book module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... allows administrators to define context-sensitive previous/next pagers for any node type. The list of nodes to be cycled through is generated by a user-selectable view, and each pager can be displayed above or below the node body or in a sidebar block. This makes it possible to duplicate the paging functions of forum.module and book.module, as well as more complex stuff like comic strip navigation.

Comment: +1: thanks for the info, i didnt know that module, looks pretty usefull! I would suggest to use the View module, if the book behavior doesnt completely fullfill his needs

Answer (score 1):

You might also check out [NodeQueue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue)